# windows 8 x64bit installation on windows 7 x32bit

Tags: windows-8

Can I install windows 8 x64 bit on windows 7 x32 bit, since my computer can operate 64bit? Is there any way to install? 
kindly provide me installation solution.

Comment: Do you mean "can I _upgrade_ Windows 7 32-bit to 8 64-bit, without having to do a fresh install"?

Comment: Sure;  Just run the installer.  Your installation will be wiped.

Comment: from where to install?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install Windows 8 64-bit if you have Windows 7 32-bit currently installed, but you must perform a clean install.  A clean install will require you to re-install all of your current software.  It is not possible to do an in-place upgrade from Windows 32-bit to 64-bit.  This is true regardless if you are switching versions or not.  You need to perform a clean install.

For clean install instructions, see: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/clean-install

Remember to backup all your files to an external drive before upgrading.

Comment: There is a problem, my PC is not showing the option of windows installation in boot menu when I press del button.It shows other options like debugging,safe mode etc,but not windows repair option or installation.so what should I do?

Comment: It sounds like it may not be booting to the installation medium, ensure it is set set in the BIOS or look for an option to choose the medium.  Alternatively, start the install when logged into Windows 7 by accessing your DVD drive from Windows File Explorer (Winkey+E) and start the setup routine from there.  This will modify the boot record to ensure you boot to the medium containing the install image without modifying BIOS options.